# Track changes (update, insert) in database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, audit, change-tracking

I administrate an web-application which is horrible in many ways and also not well documented. Since I haven't been with this project since the beginning I need to get myself a better overview. I'm using a local machine for testing and performance isn't a big problem, so if the solution is slow - it doesn't matter that much.

I would like to see what changes are made in the database  and which tables are affected(MS SQL Server 2012) when I use certain functions in the application. I have read about audit function, change tracking and change data capture. Maybe I don't fully understand those or I need something different. Any advice?

Is this what I want (tracking in which table data got changed) even possible to achieve?

So far I added an audit table (AAA_Audit2) to my copy of the database and started on a trigger which updates this table when an insert is done to my user table.

AUDIT table looks like that:

```
ID | table_name | command | time_stamp
```

While writing this I came up with an idea (help from [one trigger for all tables](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/839d67d7-b1e5-4619-a1a6-a59bee75a50c/one-trigger-for-all-tables?forum=transactsql)) and got some code to show.

Since I need to deploy this trigger for a lot of tables I wrote a trigger looking like that:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SELECT 'CREATE TRIGGER' + QUOTENAME('trgTraceDMLin' + name) + 'ON' + QUOTENAME(name)
 + 'FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE AS 

BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here
    
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[AAA_AUDIT2] (ID, table_name, command, time_stamp)

    VALUES (
    QUOTENAME(name),
    [INSERT],
    GETDATE() );
    GO'

FROM dbo.sysobjects
WHERE xtype = 'U'

END
GO
```

Now I'm getting an error in Management Studio saying "Expecting CONVERSATION". What does that mean? Googling it got me even more confused.

Thanks for reading this!

Comment: Can you post the exact, entire error.

Comment: You have a wayward `END`. I *assume* the `END` should be inside your dynamic statement, not outside of it. Also `GO` is *not* a T-SQL operator, it's an IDE operator; it will cause an error in a dynamic statement.

Comment: Incorrect syntax near 'END'. Also at the last GO- Incorrect syntax near 'GO'. Expecting CONVERSATION.

Comment: @larnu - that did the trick. looks like it's working now.

Comment: Some missing spaces on the first line also, only doesn' error because `QUOTENAME` puts `[]` around the names

Comment: Four columns specified for insert into AAA_AUDIT2 but only three values? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: One of them is an ID and gets populated automatically (IDENTITY). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply. I just thought I want to give an update, maybe someone else will get something helpful out of it.

Query to generate a trigger for all tables, probably you need a different one for insert, update and delete:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SELECT 'CREATE TRIGGER ' + QUOTENAME('trgTraceDMLin' + name) + ' ON ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE AS 

BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[AAA_AUDIT] (table_name, command, time_stamp)

    VALUES (' + CHAR(39) +
    QUOTENAME(name) + CHAR(39) + ',
    ''INSERT'',
    GETDATE() );


    END'

FROM dbo.sysobjects
WHERE xtype = 'U'
```

The query gives a result which can be copied and excuted, this will in the end generate the trigger on all tables.

This solution didn't work for the application I administrate since I ran in several deadlocks immediately.

I than changed focus and activated CDC (change data capture) on all tables, just to put a trigger on those CDC tables which write into my audit-table. It's working...somehow. But I'll thought I let you know.

Query to enable CDC on all tables:

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(100)

DECLARE @TableSchema VARCHAR(100)

DECLARE CDC_Cursor CURSOR FOR
  SELECT *
  FROM   (
         
       --  SELECT 'T' AS TableName,'dbo' AS TableSchema
         -- UNION ALL
          --SELECT 'T2' AS TableName,'dbo' AS TableSchema
           --IF want to Enable CDC on All Table, then use
         SELECT Name,SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS TableSchema
         FROM   sys.objects
         WHERE  type = 'u'
                AND is_ms_shipped <> 1
         ) CDC

OPEN CDC_Cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM CDC_Cursor INTO @TableName,@TableSchema

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1000)
      DECLARE @CDC_Status TINYINT

      SET @CDC_Status=(SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM   cdc.change_tables
          WHERE  Source_object_id = OBJECT_ID(@TableSchema+'.'+@TableName))

      --IF CDC Already Enabled on Table , Print Message
      IF @CDC_Status = 1
        PRINT 'CDC is already enabled on ' +@TableSchema+'.'+@TableName
              + ' Table'

      --IF CDC is not enabled on Table, Enable CDC and Print Message
      IF @CDC_Status <> 1
        BEGIN
            SET @SQL='EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_table
      @source_schema = '''+@TableSchema+''',
      @source_name   = ''' + @TableName
                     + ''',
      @role_name     = null;'

            EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

            PRINT 'CDC  enabled on ' +@TableSchema+'.'+ @TableName
                  + ' Table successfully'
        END

      FETCH NEXT FROM CDC_Cursor INTO @TableName,@TableSchema
  END

CLOSE CDC_Cursor

DEALLOCATE CDC_Cursor
```

Thanks for your input!

T